# Limiting generic type to a list of types. Any workarounds?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a trick or a workaround to set the generic type constrain in such a way that it only allows two types: int and Guid? Or in general a list of allowed types.

I have a massive amount of methods that looks similar to:

```
public IVehicle<TVehicleId> GetVehicle(TVehicleId? vehicleId)
{
    switch (vehicleId)
    {
        case int vid:
            return ApplicationDbContext.VehicleRepo.Single(x => x.VehicleId == vid);
        case Guid vid:
            return ApplicationDbContext.ExVehicleRepo.Single(x => x.ExVehicleId == vid);
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Vehicle Id can be either int or Guid, but was : " + typeof(TVehicleId));
    }
}
```

Where there is always a default case where NotSupportedException is thrown in case the vehicle id is neither int nor Guid.

I would like to remove the need to throw these exceptions and limit TVehicleId to int and Guid at compile time. I wonder if anybody made attempt do find a way of doing this?

Comment: Your actual problem is that you allow access to the database with two incompatible data types.  Change the method to your favourite (int or guid) and change the rest of the code.  You're creating complexity.

Comment: no, it's not possible. the "best" you can do to emulate this, besides two functions, is use `object` and type check yourself. but that's terrible. the best thing you could _actually_ do is fix your database scheme.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I wish I could do this. This is however a large chunk of legacy code with no chances to change db schemas.

Answer (score 9):

Does it need to be a generic? It sounds like overloading `GetVehicle` might be the easiest way

```cs
public IVehicle<TVehicleId> GetVehicle(int vehicleId)
{
    return ApplicationDbContext.VehicleRepo.Single(x => x.VehicleId == vehicleId);
}

public IVehicle<TVehicleId> GetVehicle(Guid vehicleId)
{
    return ApplicationDbContext.ExVehicleRepo.Single(x => x.ExVehicleId == vehicleId);
}
```

Comment: Actually it is a good question. The only pattern is that the legacy code I work on repeats this pattern in zillion places so it would require a lot of refactoring work to replace generics by overloading like here or polymorphism with one abstract class and two implementations in other places. That's why I was looking for something like in my question.